# How to populate a gridView using an ImageAdapter with a drawable array stored in xml

Tags: android, xml, gridview

I am using the sample ImageAdpater provided in the google documentation to populate a gridview with drawables. What I'm trying to do is populate the gridview with an array of drawables in an xml file.

I use `TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.log_type_icons);` to access the array from my main activity, but that doesn't work within the ImageAdapter class.

The array:

```
<string-array name="log_type_icons">
    <item>@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_headache</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_man</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_woman</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_kneel</item>
</string-array>
```

The working ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;

}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    Log.i("log tag", "gotten resources: " + mThumbIds);
    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                // attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.ic_headache,
        R.drawable.ic_kneel, R.drawable.ic_man, R.drawable.ic_woman,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher };
}
```

I know I could manually add the drawable references to the Integer array, but I reference the xml array from my main activity as well, so it would be ideal to be able to add to the xml and not have to change the code.
Does anyone have any insight into this? Am I doing something wrong or missing Something obvious?

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by using 'getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.log_type_icons);' to get the array in my main activity, then passed it to the image adapter instead of using 'getResources()' within the adapter

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the thread which is similar to your question. please check [this](http://rajivramachandran.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/android-ui-grid-layout-with-image-and-text/).

Here they used custom array of drawables. you can try your resource drawable array in place of it

Comment: My problem is how do i reference my resource library instead of it? getRsources doesn't work in the ImageAdapter

Comment: getResources().getStringArray(R.array.log_type_icons). try like this