# Accessing XML Image Array within an ImageAdapter

Tags: arrays, android-studio, gridview, baseadapter, typed-arrays

My question is very similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577125/how-to-populate-a-gridview-using-an-imageadapter-with-a-drawable-array-stored-in), however it was never properly answered.
I have an ImageAdapter setup as so;

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    int[] mImages;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, int[] images) {
        mContext = c;
        mImages = images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

And I want the images to be from an XML;

```
<integer-array name="images">
    <item>@drawable/image1</item>
    <item>@drawable/image2</item>
    <item>@drawable/image3</item>
</integer-array>
```

In my MainActivity class I have tried to get the image array and pass it into the ImageAdapter but I can't;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int images[] = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.images);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this, images));
    }
}
```

I am currently getting an error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

with my app crashing on load up. I want to make my ImageAdapter display images from an XML in my GridView.

Comment: Unclear what your issue is - you state simply that "you can't" but don't expand on that. What is the behaviour of your code - is it throwing errors - is it working but not giving you the expected output?

Comment: Sorry, as soon as a Load the app it crashes, and there is an error message of "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference",  My question is, how do I make the ImageAdapter for my GridView display images from an XML file? @henners66

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
 private int images[] = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image3};
```

instead of

```
 private int images[] = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.images);
```

Comment: This works but I want to be able to have the images come from an XML file rather than being defined in code @Malik Abu Qaoud

Comment: setImageResource only takes an int value , i don't think the array of image  (getResources().getIntArray(R.array.images)) that from XML file, is get the int value of image correctly

Comment: What is the fix to this then?

Comment: the only solution that comes on my mind is to replace

Comment: private int images[] = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.images)
to

Comment: private int images[] = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image3};